# exploding an object after moving around

Tags: objects, workflow, force-fields, cell-fracture

I'm using cell fracture effect on a cube and I want to move the object around and make it explode at a point in time using a force. but I can't move the fractured objects parent to a empty (fractured objects are applied with rigid body). even tried animation option in rigid body to move the fractured object to a point where I want but as soon as the animation is off the fractured object moves to the original location and start to explode. Is there a solution for this or any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Delay the rigid body calculation, by starting it deactivated in the Dynamics properties. You can animate when the RB should start evaluating.